# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'images')

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an error loading the web page. The code compiles everything right, but the browser crashes. Follow code:

```
import {Card} from 'react-bootstrap'
function Product({ product }){
    return(
        <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
            <a href={'/product/${product._id}'}>
                <Card.Img src={product.images}/>
            </a>

            <Card.Body>
                <a href={'/product/${product._id'}>
                    <Card.Title as="div">
                        <strong>{product.name}</strong>
                    </Card.Title>
                </a>

                <Card.Text as="div">
                    <div className="my-3">
                        {product.rating} from {product.numReviews} reviews
                    </div>
                </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Follow error:

```
 5 |    return(
   6 |        <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
   7 |            <a href={'/product/${product._id}'}>
>  8 |                <Card.Img src={product.images}/>
     | ^   9 |            </a>
  10 | 
  11 |            <Card.Body>

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'images')
```

Does anyone know what might be happening? I've already checked if I was referring to the wrong file, but at first it's all right

Comment: Are you sure `product` is not undefined?

Comment: Could you also attach the component that wrap around your `Product`?

Comment: It could be that product is on initial rendering undefined and that is why it is crashing. Also check if this <a href={'/product/${product._id}'}> should be this <a href={`product/${product._id}`}>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add some condition in order to be sure that the data is here when the component loads.

Something like this :

```
import {Card} from 'react-bootstrap'
function Product({ product }){
    return(
         <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
            <a href={'/product/${product._id}'}>
               {Boolean(product?.images) && <Card.Img src={product.images}/>}
            </a>

            <Card.Body>
                <a href={'/product/${product._id'}>
                    <Card.Title as="div">
                        <strong>{product.name}</strong>
                    </Card.Title>
                </a>

                <Card.Text as="div">
                    <div className="my-3">
                        {product.rating} from {product.numReviews} reviews
                    </div>
                </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Comment: This will still fail since there are many other references to `product` in the function

Comment: and how would it look in this stretch?
<div className="my-3">
                        {product.rating} from {product.numReviews} reviews
                    </div>

in the other parts they stopped giving errors